# How to convert a list of characters to ASCII in python?

Tags: python

Hi i’m sort of new to Python and i’m trying to convert a string of characters to ASCII in Python but I don’t know how to do that

So the relevant parts of my code are probably this

```
string = input(“Enter a line of text: “)
l = list(string)
return(l)
```

So it puts the input in a list because then it’s separate characters instead of a whole string of them but then I don’t know how to convert it to ASCII. I know I have to use ord() but I don’t understand how to do that when it’s more than one character because I don’t know what the input will be so I can’t just do like ord(A).

How can I do it?

Comment: A string is already a collection of characters. No need for the second line.

Comment: Note: Assuming OP is using Python3 (notice `input()`), the result is a list of Unicode code points, not a list of ASCII values.

Answer (score 2):

You might use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), like so:

```
string = input(“Enter a line of text: “) 
list_of_characters = list(string)
list_of_ord_values = [ord(character) for character in list_of_characters]
```

Note that, since strings are iterable, you can skip the intermediate step:

```
list_of_ord_values = [ord(character) for character in string]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = input("enter string: ")
for i in string:
    if i != ' ':            # ignoring space char
        print(i, ord(i))
```

Input

```
sample string
```

Output

```
s 115
a 97
m 109
p 112
l 108
e 101
s 115
t 116
r 114
i 105
n 110
g 103
```

The output can even be saved to another list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a for loop to loop over each character and convert them to ASCII.

You already have `l` which is a list of each character in the string. So loop over `l` and convert each character in the list to the ASCII value using ord().

Answer (score 0):

Here's a time complexity efficient way of doing it. Assuming your list is of single characters as such:

`l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
ascii_values = map(ord, l)`

This will map each character to its specified ascii value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 2, strings are encoded as ascii by default. If you are using python 3, you can convert a string to ascii using the built-in string method encode:

```
ascii = string.encode('ascii')
```

If you want this to be represented as a list, you might try encoding each separately, as the default iterated representation for ascii characters are integers. (try [x for x in b'binary string!'])

```
ascii_chars = [char.encode('ascii') for char in string]
```